# Converting a documentSnapshot to a List of objects

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My document snapshot which is returned from Firestone contains

```
{Carrots: {quantity: 2, metric: Kilograms, name: Carrots, category: Fresh Food, inShoppingList: 0}, Test Item: {quantity: 3, metric: Kilograms, name: Test Item, category: Fresh Food, inShoppingList: 0}}
```

I need to convert this into a list of item objects which contain the fields name, quantity, metric, and category. I'm  accessing the snapshot from a stateful widget as,

```
DocumentSnapshot i = Provider.of<DocumentSnapshot>(context) ?? [];
```

How can I convert this DocumentSnapshot i into a list of objects?

```
List<Item> it = i.data.map((k,v){
  return Item(name: v['name'], category: v['category']);
}).toList();
```

I tried to use map function but it gives the following error

```
type '(dynamic, dynamic) => Item' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Two things:
1. use latest version of firestore package.
2. use `Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value);` and then use it.

Comment: @AbhishekKanojia Can you explain how to use Map<String, dynamics> ?

Comment: If you understand Android, you check this article [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10).

Answer (score 0):

You can use like `snapshot.data.documents[index][<Key value>]` to get value of items